# Writing an expression for the scalar value of the electric field $E$

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, electric-fields, maxwell-equations

I am currently studying *Optics*, fifth edition, by Hecht. In chapter **2.7 Plane Waves**, the following example is given:

> An electromagnetic plane wave is described by its electric field $E$. The wave has an amplitude $E_0$, an angular frequency $\omega$, a wavelength $\lambda$, and travels at speed $c$ outward in the direction of the unit propagation vector
>
> $$\hat{\mathbf{k}} = (4\hat{\mathbf{i}} + 2\hat{\mathbf{j}})/\sqrt{20}$$
>
> (not to be confused with the unit basis vector $\hat{\mathbf{k}}$). Write an expression for the scalar value of the electric field $E$.
>
> **Solution**
>
> We want an equation of the form
>
> $$E(x, y, z, t) = E_0 e^{i\hat{\mathbf{k}} \cdot (\vec{\mathbf{r}} - \omega t)}$$
>
> Here
>
> $$\vec{\mathbf{k}} \cdot \vec{\mathbf{r}} = \dfrac{2\pi}{\lambda} \hat{\mathbf{k}} \cdot \vec{\mathbf{r}}$$
>
> and
>
> $$\vec{\mathbf{k}} \cdot \vec{\mathbf{r}} = \dfrac{2 \pi}{\lambda \sqrt{20}}(4\hat{\mathbf{i}} + 2\hat{\mathbf{j}}) \cdot (x\hat{\mathbf{i}} + y\hat{\mathbf{j}} + z\hat{\mathbf{k}})$$
>
> $$\vec{\mathbf{k}} \cdot \vec{\mathbf{r}} = \dfrac{\pi}{\lambda \sqrt{5}}(4x + 2y)$$
>
> Hence
>
> $$E = E_0e^{i \left[ \dfrac{\pi}{\lambda \sqrt{5}}(4x + 2y) - \omega t \right]}$$

I have the following questions:

1. Shouldn't $E(x, y, z, t) = E_0 e^{i\hat{\mathbf{k}} \cdot (\vec{\mathbf{r}} - \omega t)}$ be $E(x, y, z, t) = E_0 e^{i(\hat{\mathbf{k}} \cdot \vec{\mathbf{r}} - \omega t)}$?
2. Where did $\vec{\mathbf{k}} \cdot \vec{\mathbf{r}} = \dfrac{2\pi}{\lambda} \hat{\mathbf{k}} \cdot \vec{\mathbf{r}}$ come from? What is the reasoning for this?

I would greatly appreciate it if people would please take the time to clarify these points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Shouldn't $E(x, y, z, t) = E_0 e^{i\hat{\mathbf{k}} \cdot (\vec{\mathbf{r}} - \omega t)}$ be $E(x, y, z, t) = E_0
>    > e^{i(\hat{\mathbf{k}} \cdot \vec{\mathbf{r}} - \omega t)}$?

Yes. Just check the dimensions.

> 2. Where did $\vec{\mathbf{k}} \cdot \vec{\mathbf{r}} = \dfrac{2\pi}{\lambda} \hat{\mathbf{k}} \cdot \vec{\mathbf{r}}$ come
>      from? What is the reasoning for this?

The hat indicates a unit vector. Hence $\hat k = \vec k /|\vec k|$. as you probably know the wavenumber (=magnitude of the vector $\vec k$) is given by $k=2\pi/\lambda$