# Error in equations for harmonic spherical wave?

Tags: optics, waves, dimensional-analysis

I am currently studying *Optics*, fifth edition, by Hecht. In chapter **2.9 Spherical Waves**, the author says the following:

> $$\dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial{r}^2}(r \psi) = \dfrac{1}{v^2} \dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial{t}^2} (r \psi) \tag{2.71}$$
> Notice that this expression is now just the one-dimensional differential wave equation, Eq. (2.11), where the space variable is $r$ and the wavefunction is the product $(r \psi)$. The solution of Eq. (2.71) is then simply
> $$r \psi(r, t) = f(r - vt)$$
> or $$\psi(r, t) = \dfrac{f(r - vt)}{r} \tag{2.72}$$
> This represents a spherical wave progressing radially outward from the origin, at a constant speed $v$, and having an arbitrary functional form $f$. Another solution is given by
> $$\psi(r, t) = \dfrac{g(r + vt)}{r}$$
> and in this case the wave is converging toward the origin. The fact that this expression blows up at $r = 0$ is of little practical concern.
> A special case of the general solution
> $$\psi(r, t) = C_1\dfrac{f(r - vt)}{r} + C_2 \dfrac{g(r + vt)}{r} \tag{2.73}$$
> is the *harmonic spherical wave*
> $$\psi(r, t) = \left( \dfrac{\mathcal{A}}{r} \right) \cos k(r \mp vt) \tag{2.74}$$
> or $$\psi(r, t) = \left( \dfrac{\mathcal{A}}{r} \right) e^{ik(r \mp vt)} \tag{2.75}$$
> wherein the constant $\mathcal{A}$ is called the *source strength*.

Now, see my question 1. [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/535702/141502). It seems to me that the author has made the same error of writing $\cos k(r \mp vt)$ and $e^{ik(r \mp vt)}$, instead of $\cos (kr \mp vt)$ and $e^{i(kr \mp vt)}$, respectively. But this repeat of the error now makes me wonder: Is this actually an error on the part of the author, or am I misunderstanding something?

I would greatly appreciate it if people would please take the time to clarify this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's no error. $k$ has dimensions of inverse length, $r$ has dimensions of length, $v$ has dimensions of length per time, and $t$ has dimensions of time.

What you propose is dimensionally incorrect, as $kr$ is dimensionless and $vt$ has dimensions of length. On the other hand, $k(r\mp vt)$ is a valid operation, and it gives us an overall dimensionless quantity that we need for the argument of an exponential function.

You might be getting mixed up with distributing that $k$ to get $kr\mp \omega t$, which is a typical way to denote such an argument. $\omega$ had dimensions of inverse time, and $v=\omega/k$

Comment: Ahh, yes, that's what I the author did in the context of my other question https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/535702/141502: $$E(x, y, z, t) = E_0 e^{i\hat{\mathbf{k}} \cdot (\vec{\mathbf{r}} - \omega t)}$$ So the user Semoi's answer https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/535706/141502 was correct in saying that the author made an error with $E(x, y, z, t) = E_0 e^{i\hat{\mathbf{k}} \cdot (\vec{\mathbf{r}} - \omega t)}$, and it should actually be $E(x, y, z, t) = E_0 e^{i(\hat{\mathbf{k}} \cdot \vec{\mathbf{r}} - \omega t)}$?

Comment: @ThePointer Yes. Both of your questions are essentially about the same issue.

Comment: I think being able to recall the author's last error made me think that this was also an error. But, as you say, the last one actually *was* an error, whereas this one is *not* and is actually slightly different, since we have $v$ (the velocity) instead of $\omega$ (the angular frequency), right?

Comment: @ThePointer Yes